# Transform docx to html raises python MemoryError

Tags: python, html, windows, openxml, docx

I have a function that converts a docx to html and a large docx file to be converted.
The problem is this function is part of a bigger program and the converted html is parsed afterwards so I cannot afford to use another converter without impacting the rest of the code (which is not wanted). Running on python 2.7.13 installed on 32-bit, but changing to 64-bit is also not desired.
This is the function:

```
import logging
from ooxml import serialize
def trasnformDocxtoHtml(inputFile, outputFile):
    logging.basicConfig(filename='ooxml.log', level=logging.INFO)
    dfile = ooxml.read_from_file(inputFile)

    with open(outputFile,'w') as htmlFile:
        htmlFile.write( serialize.serialize(dfile.document))
```

and here's the error:

```
>>> import library
>>> library.trasnformDocxtoHtml(r'large_file.docx', 'output.html')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "library.py", line 9, in trasnformDocxtoHtml
    dfile = ooxml.read_from_file(inputFile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ooxml\__init__.py", line 52, in read_from_file
    dfile.parse()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ooxml\docxfile.py", line 46, in parse
    self._doc = parse_from_file(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ooxml\parse.py", line 655, in parse_from_file
    document = parse_document(doc_content)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ooxml\parse.py", line 463, in parse_document
    document.elements.append(parse_table(document, elem))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ooxml\parse.py", line 436, in parse_table
    for p in tc.xpath('./w:p', namespaces=NAMESPACES):
  File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 1583, in lxml.etree._Element.xpath
MemoryError
no mem for new parser
MemoryError
```

Could I somehow increase the buffer memory in python? Or fix the function without impacting the html output format?

Comment: How large is the file you are trying to parse?

Comment: @IonicSolutions It doesn't seem so big, it's 2MB resp. almost 8000 pages. I've read other people struggling with similar issues and their files where GB sizes. Compared mine seems a piece of cake, but still the MemoryError is there.

Comment: Have you tried with a smaller file? The only related issue I could find is [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252010/getting-a-memory-error-when-parsing-a-large-xml-file-in-python), but I'm not sure whether the solutions there are applicable to your problem.

Comment: @IonicSolutions Yes, I did try with a smaller file and it works fine. I checked the post you suggested but it's not helpful, unfortunately.